# How to run a python script from django views

Tags: python, html, django

How to execute python script passing an argument from html page in django views and want to get output from the python script and display it in the same html page.

My views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    context = {}
    shortdes = request.GET.get('shortdes')
    context['shortdes'] = shortdes
    return render(request, 'webapp/ttgeniehome.html', context)
```

Want to pass shortdes variable as an argument to python script (eg: script.py which is available on the same directory where views.py file exists.

Comment: OK. What's stopping you?

Comment: 1. It's not safe 2. Why don't you put it into a model function? View is not supposed to do such thing. 3. What's the exact problem? (What have you tried)

Comment: I am new to django and python. Not sure how to include script in views.py any sample code or reference would be helpful

Comment: `from script import shortdes` after `from.shortcuts import render`

Comment: can you provide more details about how to invoke the script with arguments?